# Conditional Redirects in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Context: I have a blog with a good amount of content indexed by Google. For example, all the content is indexed as [www.site.com/post1](http://www.site.com/post1). I am migrating my blog to NextJS and I have scoped the blog posts to [www.site.com/blog/post1](http://www.site.com/blog/post1). I was able to easily use the redirects with 301 to maintain the SEO for these blog posts. However, I am running into an issue where links like [www.site.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.site.com/sitemap.xml) are also redirected to [www.site.com/blog/sitemap.xml](http://www.site.com/blog/sitemap.xml). Is there a way to redirect only if the pattern doesn't match some path? Here is my section on redirects in next.config.js

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug',
        destination: '/blog/:slug',
        permanent: true// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      },
      {
        source: '/sitemap.xml',
        destination: '/sitemap.xml',
        permanent: false// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think order would matter, have you tried putting your sitemap rule first?

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/sitemap.xml',
        destination: '/sitemap.xml',
        permanent: false// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      },
      {
        source: '/:slug',
        destination: '/blog/:slug',
        permanent: true// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      }
    ]
  }
```

Otherwise, may need to use regex

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: `/:slug(^((?!sitemap\.xml).)*$)`,
        destination: '/blog/:slug',
        permanent: true// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      },
      {
        source: '/sitemap.xml',
        destination: '/sitemap.xml',
        permanent: false// Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I tried ordering them that didn't seem to help but will try the second option you mentioned